$s,t\mid k\Rightarrow st\mid k\,$ holds only when $s,t$ are coprime
In the problem (below) we are asked to show: if $a \pmod {st} = b \pmod {st}$, then $a \pmod s = b \pmod s$ and $a \pmod t = b \pmod t$. I did this part of the question. Then we are asked, what makes the converse true? The answer is, that $\gcd (s, t) = 1$. How can this be shown?
Here is the actual problem (from Gallian, Contemporary Abstract Algebra 6E):
Let $a$, $b$, $s$, and $t$ be integers. If $a \pmod {st} = b \pmod {st}$, show that $a \pmod s = b \pmod s$ and $a \pmod t = b \pmod t$. What condition on $s$ and $t$ is needed to make the converse true?
My question is a little bit different than this one: x≡a (mod m) and x≡a(mod n) implies x≡a (mod mn) (and a few others like it). Usually in similar questions it is a supposition that $m$ and $n$ (in my case the $s$ and the $t$) are relatively prime. In my question, I am asking, how can we show that this is the case?
Here is my attempt at showing the converse (I don't think it is correct):
The converse would be that if $a \equiv b \pmod s$ and $a \equiv b \pmod t$, then $a \equiv b \pmod {st}$. Suppose that $a \equiv b \pmod s$ and $a \equiv b \pmod t$, then $s$ divides $a − b$ and $t$ divides $a − b$. There exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $a − b = ms$ and $a − b = nt$. In order for $st$ to appear as a factor of $a − b$, $s$ and $t$ must be relatively prime. Or in other words, $\gcd (s, t) = 1$.
Consider:
\begin{align*}
    a - b & = ms \\
          & = (nt)s \\
          & = n(ts)
\end{align*}
Above, if $s$ divided $t$ or $t$ divided $s$, then they would not appear as factors alongside one another. We would not have $st$ as a factor.
EDIT:
My question was closed due to being similar to this question: $ d_1,d_2\mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(d_1,d_2)\mid n\,\ $ [LCM Universal Property or Definition]. My question is slightly different. This question is more open-ended. This question is seeking any satisfactory proof as an answer. In my question, I am asking about a specific condition: $\gcd (s, t) = 1$, and why it forces the result: $a \pmod {st} = b \pmod {st}$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Note that $a\equiv b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$ is the same as $n\mid a-b$, and so what you are asking is the same as
$$s\mid x\ \mathrm{and}\ t\mid x\implies st\mid x$$
But if $s\mid x$ and $t\mid x$, then $x$ is a common multiple of $s$ and $t$, so it must be a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(s,t)$. If $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime, then the lcm is just the product, and that is the claim. But in general, you may or may not have it. You can always take $x$ to be the lcm itself, and then it won't hold. For a concrete example,$\newcommand{\Mod}[3]{#1\equiv#2\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #3)}$ $\Mod{12}04$ and $\Mod{12}06$ but $12\not\equiv0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 24)$. You can always do this by replacing $4$ and $6$ with any not-coprime pair of integers.
Hope this helps. :)

so my question really becomes, when does $s | a - b$ and $t | a - b$ imply that $st | a - b$? as opposed to why must

at the end of your answer, you say You can always do this by replacing 4 and 6 with any not-coprime pair of integers, but if you did this, then you would also have to replace $12$ with something?

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)
